# как правильно подключить переменные sass к angular 6

Tags: sass, angular5, препроцессор, компоненты

есть файл **_variables.sass** в нем хранятся все глобальные переменные
но для *компонентов* они не доступны.
правильно ли будет подключать таким образом в ***КАЖДЫЙ*** компонент эти переменные ?    `@import "variables"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, конечно. Вы можете также для удобства задать алиас для директории где лежит Ваш файл `_variables.scss`. В `angular.json` `architect => build => options` после свойства `styles` нужно добавить:

```
"stylePreprocessorOptions": {
    "includePaths": [
        "src/scss"
    ]
}
```

Это учитывая, что файл `_variables.scss` лежит в папке `src/scss`, но Вы можете указать свою. После этого в любом компоненте при любой вложенности директорий - Вы можете спокойно писать `@import 'variables';`, компилятор знает где искать.